# Serve media files in Django as seekable (with HTTP PartialResponse)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

**I know that it will be easier to serve these video files with another server like Apache, but I can't use it now.**

I have some uploaded videos in the `media` folder using Django (using those `FileField` models). Now, I have set up a way to stream those videos, but the problem is, the video is not seeking.

This can be fixed by implementing some sort of Streaming Response ([maybe this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.StreamingHttpResponse), but I am unsure and don't know how to do.) that implements `HTTP PARTIAL RESPONSE`. Any way to implement this?

I'm using media files as specified [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files) (see the MEDIA_ROOT, MEDIA_URL parts.)

My settings.py -

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media/")
MEDIA_URL = "media/"
...
'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.media',
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
]
```

My urls.py -

```
urlpatterns = [...]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                      document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally solved this with the help of this module - [django-ranged-response](https://github.com/wearespindle/django-ranged-fileresponse). (Install it with `pip install django-ranged-response`).

Then, in my app's `urls.py` -

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
url(r'^videos/(?P<video_file>[0-9a-zA-Z _!@$|:;&*()"\'.,<>+=`-]+)/$',
    views.video_stream, name='v_stream'),
]
```

In the `views.py` file -

```
import os, mimetypes
from django.http import HttpResponseNotFound
from ranged_response import RangedFileResponse

...

def video_stream(request, video_file):
    _file = FILE_PATH + video_file
    if not os.path.isfile(_file):
        return HttpResponseNotFound()
    response = RangedFileResponse(
        request, open(_file, 'rb'),
        content_type=mimetypes.guess_type(_file)[0]
    )
    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(_file)
    return response
```

Comment: Is there any new solution for newest Django?